# Обмен данными между iframe js через postMessage + SAME ORIGIN POLICY

Tags: javascript, iframe, javascript-events

Как с помощю postMessage считать  информацию с одного айфрейма(iframe) и записать в другой? Это был скороченый вариант вопроса. Помогите дураку вопрос жизни и смерти. 
Смотрите есть такая задача:

- из li-шек(внутриних частей ul) и их атрибутов name надо извлечь данные
  и на их основе построить форму. Пример пункта
  формы:'dataform1
   .
- Затем, надо передать html этой формы во второй айфрейм (id =
  second) после того как в нем все удалите (прикол в том что за 2(два) iframe  ссылаются на один файл(или так нельзя?)).
- Загвоздка(здесь и возникли проблемы) в том что Передавать надо ***postMessage***(желательно)  или
  contentDocument. Action в теге

  с class="pm".
- Еще одна проблема а    как отправить форму **обычным** способом **(не
  ajax)** через js Метод    POST.
  Я то это сделал напрямую через 'window.frames.second.document.body.innerHTML' но проблема в том что не это не безопасно и браузер ругается
  Помогите пожалуйста. Прикрепляю код айфрейма и код самого сайта. Зарание благодарочка.

Это айфрейм:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="n">dflf;dfkl</p>
<p>fddfd</p>
<p>fddfd</p>
<p>fddfd</p>

<p>fddfd</p>
<ul>
  <li name="dataform1">hi</li>
  <li name="dataform2">my</li>
  <li name="dataform3">name</li>
  <li name="dataform4">is</li>
  <li name="dataform5">coo1kie</li>
  <li name="dataform6">first</li>
  <li name="dataform7">second</li>
  <li name="dataform8">third</li>
  <li name="dataform9">fourth</li>
  <li name="dataform10">fifth</li>
  <li name="dataform11">sixth</li>
  <li name="dataform12">seventh</li>
  <li name="dataform13">eighth</li>
</ul>

<p class="pm">http://185.174.63.223//ajaxishere/aj.php"</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Это основа:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe id="first" name="first" src="iframe.html" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scrips"></iframe>
<iframe id="second" name="second" src="iframe.html" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scrips"></iframe>

</body>
<script >
   

function funk(){
    var dat =$('iframe#first').contents().find("li"),//виделяем данные из li
  //  console.log(dat[0].innerHTML);
    dnams=new Array(),
    dval=new Array(),
    adrs=$('iframe#first').contents().find("p.pm").html();//виделяю адрес
    //console.log(nadrs[0].innerHTML);
    for(var i = 0; i<dat.length; i++){
        dnams[i]=dat[i].getAttribute("name");
        dval[i]=dat[i].innerHTML;
    }
    
    
 window.frames.second.document.body.innerHTML='<form method="post" action="'+adrs+'" id="outf"></form>';
    
    for(var i = 0;i<dnams.length;i++){
         $('iframe#second').contents().find("#outf").append('<label>'+dnams[i]+'</label><br><input type="text" name="'+dnams[i]+'" value="'+dval[i]+'"> <br> ');
    }
     $('iframe#second').contents().find("#outf").append('<input type="submit">');
    }
   
setTimeout(funk,1000);
</script>
</html>
```